# Neutron conversion to energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass-energy, neutrons

Numerical:

If a neutron be entirely converted into energy how much energy would be produced. ($M_n = 1.6743\times 10^{-27}$kg.)

Explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Einstein's Mass-Energy Equivalence $$E=mc^2$$

Now enter the value of m, where m is the mass converted to energy, and c is speed of light$
 =3\times 10^8$m/s